# Not able to upload a document on sharepoint folder using java

Tags: java, sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I Want to upload the document into Sharepoint Folder.

Below are my observation and Progress

- I have tried to pick a document from Local Machine and Upload the same into Local Machine (Some Another Folder)
  This is working fine
- Now all I wanted to to change is instead of uploading it to some local folder I want to upload it into sharepoint folder

Below Is the Code That I have Tried.

```
File baseDir = new File(ApplicationProperties.getInstance().getAttachmentUploadBaseDirPath());
if (!baseDir.exists()) {
    baseDir.mkdir();
}

File complaintDir = new File("https://apps.companyname.com/sites/Shared Documents/Test" + "\\" + complaintNumber);
if (!complaintDir.exists()) {
    complaintDir.mkdir();
}

file = new File(complaintDir + "\\"+ filename);
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging and finally got my answer. Steps which I followed:

1. I tried to create rest api in postman. But I was getting forbidden
   403 as status code.
2. I tried following blog as I came to know I
   have to generate client id and client secret on sharepoint site.  So
   Here is the blog which is followed :
   http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/

Happy Coding!
Thanks.